# Pagination, Sort, Filter fails in Angular Material Table for big JSON file

Tags: json, angular, express, angular-material

I am trying to send JSON with more than 50K entries via an express server to Angular. In the deployment I can see all the entries in the format of Angular Material table. However the pagination, sort and filter feature of the tables are not working at all.

Here is the ts file

```
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTable, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { ViewDataService } from './modules/view-data.service';
import { ThrowStmt } from '@angular/compiler';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export interface DataEntries {

  key: string;

  value: String;

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
  

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'TD';

  dataSource: any;  //MatTableDataSource<Student>;

  

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['key', 'value'];
  //columns: string[] = ['id','name','email','gender']

  public orderByKey(a: any, b: any) {
    return a.key;
  }
  private paginator: MatPaginator;
  private sort: MatSort;

  @ViewChild(MatSort) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
    this.sort = ms;
    this.setDataSourceAttributes();
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    this.paginator = mp;
    this.setDataSourceAttributes();
  }

  setDataSourceAttributes() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

  }
  //@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort: MatSort;
  //@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  dataEntries: DataEntries[] = []
  
  constructor(private viewdata: ViewDataService) {
   
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.viewdata.getData().then(response => {
      this.dataEntries = response.data;
      console.log(this.dataEntries);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataEntries);
      console.log(this.dataSource);
      this.dataSource = this.dataSource.filteredData;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator);
  
    })
 

    //Called after the constructor, initializing input properties, and the first call to ngOnChanges.
    //Add 'implements OnInit' to the class.
    
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

  }
}
```

Here is the template

```
<h1>Placeholder Table</h1>


<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="formControlName"
             type="text"
             placeholder="Search" (keyup)="applyFilter($event)">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource | keyvalue:orderByKey" class="mat-elevation-z4" matSort>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="key">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Key
    </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.key}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> value</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  
  
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
<mat-paginator [length]="dataEntries.length"
              [pageSize]="100"
              [pageSizeOptions]="[2, 5, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Here is the express file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const jason = require('../public/jsons/en-GB.json');
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jason)));
  console.log('Test');
  
});

module.exports = router;
```

Please let me know why they are failing

Comment: Your code has to work fine but not in an async environment. You have to await the paginator for the data to be loaded. You can change your http api obsrvable to a promise and use ```async-await``` to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.component.ts`

```
async ngOnInit(): void {
   const response = await this.viewdata.getData();
      this.dataEntries = response.data;
      console.log(this.dataEntries);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataEntries);
      console.log(this.dataSource);
      this.dataSource = await this.dataSource.filteredData;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator
    }
 
    
  }
```

In your `http-service`

```
getData(){
 return http.get('/').toPromise();
}
```

Comment: Hey, I am using axios for get: 

async getData() {
    return await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/viewData');
  }

and I tried adding await and async to the function as described above. However the pagination and other features are still breaking. I am also getting warnings that await on sort and paginator are having no effects.

Comment: I have used just this piece of code in to apply pagination. and used a separate function to retrieve data based on page number rather than importing everything and then paginating .```@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;```

Comment: `@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;`
 I have updated the previous declarations with these lines. However I am still facing the same issue.